# Is conditional or future geyrus (conversion to Judaism) possible?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

1. If someone goes through the process of geyrus (conversion to Judaism), and (prior to the conversion) he says  "I'm only interested in becoming Jewish if-so-and-so happens tomorrow", Is his geyrus valid, if the condition is met?
2. If someone goes through the process of Geyrus (conversion to Judaism), and (prior to the conversion) he says  "I'm only interested in becoming Jewish next week, month, year... etc." Is his geyrus valid, when the time comes?

Does it make a difference if he wants the conversion to be retroactive or only from the time/ condition given?

Comment: Sound like a Kattan